# A proverb to imply two people cannot get along together

Tags: expressions, proverbs

For two people who usually don't get along and often argue for any insignificant matter or in general don't see eye to eye, there is a proverb in our language which says:

> - Their water does not flow in the same stream.

Etymology: the religeous story behind this proverb goes back to the time of the prophet Moses when the twelve brothers couldn't reach to an agreement about the source water and Moses made twelve devided sources for each one so that they had no any other reason to fight together!

I have already found a couple of equivalents in English for this concept through my researches which I will list them below:

> - They will never go in double harness!
> - They're not in line!

Please let me know how usually a native speaker would imply there is no mutual understanding between two peopple?

Please note that, the proverb/expression in my question should be so neutral and multilateral that it could be used to describe the quality of two people who had even chimistry between them, but now they................

Answer (score 2):

They never see eye to eye.
They fight like cats and dogs.
They are like chalk and cheese.

Comment: Thank you @Showsni, but you didn't let me know anything about my own suggestions! Please tell me more about them. :)

Comment: @Showsni's answers are all very good.  There's also the quote from Rudyard Kipling: "never the twain shall meet".  As for your own suggestions, I have never heard the expression "they will never go in double harness".  I think it is very obscure at best.  And "they're not in line" would normally mean something like "they are not in agreement with everyone else", not "they don't agree with each other".  After all, two people are always in line with each other: you need at least three things to be able to have them not all in line!